# AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks' (NER)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using macOS terminal to run *train.py* file, which can be found in this [Github link](https://github.com/HassanAzzam/Arabic-NER/blob/master/train.py) but I keep getting the following error:

```
Arabic-NER $ python train.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
Loading Word Embedding model...
loaded model in 368.90753722190857 seconds
2019-12-18 21:11:19.329197: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fb88580c330 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-12-18 21:11:19.329702: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 130, in <module>
    train_model, crf_layer = model.build_model()
  File "/Name Entity Recognition /HassanAzzam/Arabic-NER/model.py", line 21, in build_model
    output_layer = crf_layer(bi_gru)
  File "/Name Entity Recognition /HassanAzzam/Arabic-NER/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Name Entity Recognition /HassanAzzam/Arabic-NER/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 475, in __call__
    previous_mask = _collect_previous_mask(inputs)
  File "/Name Entity Recognition /HassanAzzam/Arabic-NER/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1441, in _collect_previous_mask
    mask = node.output_masks[tensor_index]
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks'
```

Also, here's *model.py*:

```
import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, GRU, Embedding, Dropout, Activation, Masking
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional, GlobalMaxPool1D, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras_contrib.layers import CRF



def build_model():
    crf_layer = CRF(9)
    input_layer = Input(shape=(None,300,))
#     embedding = Embedding(212, 20, input_length=None, mask_zero=True)(input_layer)
    mask_layer = Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(212, 300))(input_layer)
    bi_gru = Bidirectional(GRU(10, return_sequences=True))(mask_layer)
    bi_gru = TimeDistributed(Dense(10, activation="relu"))(bi_gru)
    output_layer = crf_layer(bi_gru)
    return Model(input_layer, output_layer), crf_layer
```

I'm using TensorFlow 2.0 and Python 3.6.6.

**Note**: in the *train.py* file, in line 8, I have added *tensorflow* before *keras*. 
So, it's `from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical`.

The full Github repository can be found [here](https://github.com/HassanAzzam/Arabic-NER)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing the following versions:

Seqeval:
`pip install seqeval==0.0.5`

Keras:
`pip install keras==2.2.4`

Tensorflow:
`pip install tensorflow==1.14.0`

I also added `from keras.models import *` in the beginning of each file